# Change a host object's prototype function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, prototype

I'd like to execute some code every time a call to `appendChild` is made. Let's just assume I have no way of knowing where or when it will be called. I figured I could use prototype's to do it, but they don't seem to be working:

```
var actAppendChild = Element.prototype.appendChild;
Element.prototype.appendChild = function(node){
    actAppendChild.call(this,node);

    //execute custom code here...
    console.log("foo");
}

document.body.appendChild(someNode);
```

But "foo" doesn't print to the console, nor any code inside the new prototype function, for that matter. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly is not working? Because here it is

Comment: Your code works fine. I tested it here -- http://jsfiddle.net/9P3hr/

Comment: You're using Internet Explorer, aren't you.

Comment: Older browsers are not crucial. Maybe IE8+

Comment: Well it works fine in Firefox. What makes you think it's *not* working?

Comment: It works in newer browsers but you won't get far in IE with that. For one thing, I don't think IE 8 and below defines `HTMLElement`.

Comment: I'm using FF13 and "foo" doesn't show up in the console.

Comment: When I run the code, the `console.log("foo")` doesn't appear to execute. It doesn't show in firebug or the built in console. I try substituting the "custom code" in the new appendChild for other code (like `alert('foo')`) and none of it is getting executed.

Comment: Actually I'm not so sure it *does* work in Firefox, @David - do you get a console.log?  If you make the function do anything else, can you see the effect?

Comment: I've done some tests in Firefox 13, and it seems that `prototype.appendChild` of `HTMLBodyElement`, `HTMLElement` **and** `Element`are **unique**, in the sense that they none of the methods are inherit. Hence, overwriting `Element.prototype.appendChild` is not noticed, because `document.body.appendChild` inherits the method from `HTMLBodyElement`.

Comment: @RobW wow that's weird - anyway I was just fooling with the new x-tag code from Mozilla, which uses a clever trick to track DOM updates. The trick involves CSS animations (so no old IE support) to trigger an "animationstart" event from a do-nothing animation. It's pretty cool :-)

Comment: @Pointy Sounds cool indeed! I've found [this blog post](http://www.backalleycoder.com/2012/04/25/i-want-a-damnodeinserted/) which explains this feature. OT: Morale of the story: Do not rely on extending host object's prototype for cross-browser consistent behaviour.

Comment: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-script-coord/2012AprJun/0255.html This is recent and I think perhaps the consequences not well understood. It was framed in terms of say A.prototype.method.call(b). But the real issue is that A.prototype.method != B.prototype.method despite having the same name, doing the same thing, and up until the last month, actually being the same function.

Comment: Another thing to note, that I've noticed while working on a project that required me to make an IE5/6 ONLY application work in newer browsers is when adding/overwriting methods on document, some browsers don't have document inherit from HTMLElement. Instead, they have a HTMLDocument class. You should look at modifying that prototype.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that it works fine even on IE8+, Safari, Chrome and Opera.
Just an advice: it's always a best practice to wrap your code in a closure to avoid polluting the global namespace, like so:

```
(function(){
  var actAppendChild = Element.prototype.appendChild;
  ....
}());
```